# NSTextAttachment not showing up in Today Notification Center Widget

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I have a notification center widget that has a table view with table view cells. In the cells I have a label that I would like to show up with text + an image. The image being included as an NSTextAttachment. I have the following code inside the app:

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageWithData:item.image];
NSAttributedString *itemImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
NSAttributedString *itemName = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", item.name]];
NSMutableAttributedString *itemString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:itemImage];
[itemString appendAttributedString:itemName];
cell.nameLabel.attributedText = itemString;
```

This code works while inside the app but I am also trying to use in my widget (and therefore TodayViewController). When displayed in the widget, no image shows up on the label. If I stop while running through this code I can see that the attachment.image is getting set properly. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out later on, after I had set `cell.nameLabel.attributedText = itemString;` I was later setting cell.nameLabel.text = itemString, so it was overriding the attributed string

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
```

to

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithData:nil ofType:nil];
```

This might be the same issue from this post: [NSTextAttachment image not displayed on iOS 8 devices (with iOS7.1 sdk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006267/nstextattachment-image-not-displayed-on-ios-8-devices-with-ios7-1-sdk)

Comment: Unfortunately makes no difference